# Column width goes back to orignal when importing .txt files EXCEL 2013

Tags: excel, text-files

I have different .txt files which I frequently have to import on the same sheet on excel. The problem I am having is that after I manually adjust the width of the columns, and then import a new .txt file, the size of the columns go back to the original size. Is there a way to lock the column width after adjusting it to the desired size. I did use the 'Protect Sheets' option, which enabled me to still edit the sheet(as I checked all the boxes except 'Format Column' and 'Format Row') but it didn't allow me to import any more .txt files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than opening the file in Excel every time, you can create a new Excel file that uses the text file as a data source. When ever there is a change to the data, you can just right-clight and update, and everything else in the "parent" Excel file stays formatted correctly.

In Excel 2007/2010, go to Data, From Text and select your text file.

This link elaborates on the subject :
http://blogs.office.com/2010/06/10/importing-text-files-in-an-excel-sheet/